# How to more easily access a ContentItem's fields in a CSHTML view?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have written a helper function (I'm quite proud of this it - look what I can do!) that does what I need. Is there a built in way, though, to access a `ContentItem`'s fields without having first to get the "main" `ContentPart`? The word "main" here means the `ContentPart` with the same name as the `ContentType`.

```
@functions
{
    dynamic GetMainPartFromContentItem(ContentItem item)
    {
        var contentType = item.TypeDefinition.Name;
        var parts = item.Parts as List<Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart>;
        dynamic mainPart = parts.First(p => p.PartDefinition.Name.Equals(contentType));
        return mainPart;
    }
}

dynamic mainPart = GetMainPartFromContentItem(contentItem);
var shortTitle = mainPart.ShortTitle.Value; // access an InputField's value
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a ContentType called Page with a field called Topic you can do:

```
dynamic item = Model.ContentItem;

string topic = item.Page.Topic.Value;
```

Basically when you add fields directly to the content item, they are being added to a part on your content item called whatever your content type is, in this case Page

Comment: While that is helpful, it doesn't answer the question: "Is there a built in way, though, to access a ContentItem's fields without having first to get the "main" ContentPart?" When you write `item.Page`, you are accessing what I am calling the "main" content part.

Comment: I don't really understand, that functionality is built into Orchard to allow you to access fields

Comment: Sometime I want to access the fields, and I do not know the name of the content type. In that case, I cannot use the dot notation.

Comment: Ah, then no, you wouldn't be able to. I do agree that the way it is done is a little odd

Comment: No, there is no built-in way, because the same field name can be used on more than one part. Special-casing the part named like the type would probably make sense however, as there is a relevant convention here. Maybe we should fall back to looking for fields on that part when a name on a content item can't be resolved to the name of a part. Please file a bug if you want.